# autoincrement of Sequence Number During an update in the Merge Statement in Snowflake

Tags: sequence, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have written a Merge statement to perform Insert/Update in the snowflake and it was observed that the sequence in the Target table gets increment,  While executing the Insert Clause but also While update statement also got satisfied/working . can any one help me how to fix this issue?

```
create or replace table target_table (id integer , description varchar);

create or replace table source_table2 (id integer , description varchar);

create or replace sequence seq1;
```

Below is the Merge statement I have used...

```
  merge into target_table using source_table2 
    on target_table.id = source_table2.id
    when matched then 
        update set target_table.description = 'I am Changing'
     when not matched then insert (ID, description) values (seq1.nextval, source_table2.description);
```

can anyone explain how the sequence were processed at the backend and why there was a skip of numbers seen in the Snow Flake?

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not saying that the sequence value on the target table is getting a new number on the updated record, then you are seeing expected behavior with the sequence in Snowflake.  The documentation here is a good read on this:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences.html

Comment: If you need to generate sequence with no gaps, you can create a sequence and then run a ROW_NUMBER over it. 
Although, in this case you'd need to do a little extra work to get that into the merge.

Comment: Thanks David, Can you share any example it would be great needful..